# I cannot define my matrices for calculate spearman correlation matrix Python 3.6

Tags: python, file-io, correlation, coefficients, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to write a code that will find the Pearson and Spearman correlation of a matrix from Excel than show it if it's correlated or not according to my threshold. My code is like this:

```
import pandas   

Correlation_coefficient = input ("PEARSON OR SPEARMAN?")   
A = "PEARSON"   
B = "SPEARMAN"

    if Correlation_coefficient == B:
    print ("Spearman code will appear here")
```

---

My problem is that we can not calculate spearman correlation coefficient with my excel file because my numbers are in matrix defined and spearman does not accept the values in matrix.How can I calculate spearman correlation cofficient?

Comment: open(), write(), close()

Comment: did you tried `S0.corr('spearman')`  and S0.corr('pearson') ?

Comment: Yes I tried it works on pearson correlation calculation not for spearman because our values are in  matrix defined.